# How do I work out what percent of my customers will be girls and what percent will be boys?

Tags: statistics

I know that **33.3333% of all girls** questions would **buy** my product and that **80% of all boys** questioned would **buy** it.

What i don't know is how to work out is statistically what percentage of our **customers** will be boys and what percentage will girls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $G$ = the person is a girl and $C$ = the person is a customer. Assume that a *customer* is defined to be anyone who buys your product. Then we are given that:

> - $P(C|G)=0.333...=1/3$
> - $P\left(C|\overline{G}\right) = 0.8 = 4/5$

We are asked to find: $P(G|C)$ and $P\left(\overline{G}|C\right)$

The following identity will be useful:

> $$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \text{ and } B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(A)P(B|A)}{P(A)P(B|A) + P\left(\overline{A}\right)P\left(B|\overline{A}\right)}$$